# WPF radio button icon change (the circle itself)

Tags: wpf, radio-button

I would like to have a group of radio buttons which the circles for un-selected and selected mode are changed to circle icons that I designed.

It that possible to do that in WPF?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a style and override the default template for RadioButtons. Something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Grid Width="13" Height="13">
                                <Ellipse x:Name="Border" StrokeThickness="2">
                                    <Ellipse.Stroke>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="Pink" Offset="1" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Ellipse.Stroke>
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                   EndPoint="0,1">
                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="Orange" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="Red"
                                  Offset="1.0" />
                                                </GradientStopCollection>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="CheckMark"
                   Margin="4"
                   Visibility="Collapsed">
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Purple" />
                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>
                            </Grid>
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                      <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,0,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                    </BulletDecorator>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks. But while this style changed the radio style, it deleted the text. Also, how do I put an image instead of shapes or new colors, and how do I distinguish between checked style and un-checked style?

Comment: Yep, for the text you also need to add the ContentPresenter part from the original template (edited the code above). For images, you probably need to replace the Ellipse with an Image.

Comment: Great!! that's exactly what I needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, it is possible. You can override default *ControlTemplate* and create style for your own radiobutton. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/radiobutton-styles-and-templates) is an example, you can also use Style Snooper to see the WPF built-in radio button style (a big piece of XAML code:) )

Comment: Thanks a lot :). How can I override the template to be an image rather than a shape? How do I distinguish between selected style and un-selected style?

Comment: It isn't a single line of code, check the example above. Selected and unselected states are handled using visual states and triggers